# Date Format JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I want to format `2012-05-04 00:00:00.0` to `04-MAY-2012`. i have tried it with below steps.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    Date date;
    String dateformat = "";
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("2012-05-04 00:00:00.0");
        sdf.applyPattern("DD-MON-RR");
        dateformat = sdf.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i got below exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-05-04 00:00:00.0"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at com.am.test.Commit.main(Example.java:33)`
```

How could i do this?

Comment: Isn't there an extra 'T' in your first pattern?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here, this works:

1. Remove the extra 'T' in your first pattern
2. The second format is incorrect, it should be dd-MMM-yyyy.

Take a look at the Javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class temp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        Date date;
        String dateformat = "";
        try {
            date = sdf.parse("2012-05-04 00:00:00.0");
            sdf.applyPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            dateformat = sdf.format(date);
            System.err.println(dateformat);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you remove the `'T'` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Using this pattern:

```
sdf.applyPattern("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

Don't using this:

```
sdf.applyPattern("DD-MON-RR");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

Date date;
String dateformat = "";
try {
    date = sdf.parse("2012-05-04 00:00:00.0");
    sdf.applyPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    dateformat = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(dateformat);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Date oldFormatedDate = null;
try {
    oldFormatedDate = sdf.parse("2012-05-04 00:00:00.0");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").
           format(oldFormatedDate));
}
```