# Netbeans Database datetime issue

Tags: java, database, datetime, arraylist, format

The error message I'm getting when I compile this is "The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect"

When the date object is being passed in from the History ArrayList, it's format is '19-Apr-2013'

I know the database's format is 'Year-Month-Day'. Is there any way for me to convert my date object to the correct format for the database?

```
for ( Patient p: pList )
{
    patientInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.PATIENT VALUES (" + p.getPatientNum() +
        + ", '" + p.getPatientName() + "', '" + p.getPatientAddress() + "', '"
        + p.getPatientPhone() + "')";
    res = stmt.executeUpdate(patientInsertSQL);
    System.out.println(res);
    ArrayList<History> tempHistList = p.getHistory();
    String histSelect = "select * from SHAUN.HISTORY";
    result = stmt.executeQuery(histSelect);
    for ( History h: tempHistList )
    {
        historyInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.HISTORY VALUES (" + h.getHistID()
          + ", '" + h.getConditionName() + "', '" + h.getMedication() + "', '"
          + h.getDateOccured() + "', " + p.getPatientNum() + ")";
        res = stmt.executeUpdate(historyInsertSQL);
        System.out.println(res);
        //Loop Checker
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println("In the History Loop " + i);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("In the loop!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this post [SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444091/date-format-java)

it should help you get what you want to achieve.

eg:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
try {
     date = formatter.parse(yourdate.toString());
     formatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
     dateformat = formatter.format(yourdate);
     System.err.println(dateformat);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Javadoc of 
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)